# Can't Get Previous page URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have facing an issue for getting previous page url while using document.referrer property using JQuery.
When i'm going to click back button on current UI page(page2.html), it'll go to the previous page(page1.html) but again i want to come back to the current page(page2.html), It'll work instated of before clicking the back button i press f5 key, here the document.referrer property value is getting empty so that i can't get back to the current page. If anybody knows this issue kindly let me know how can i fix?

Thanks & regards,

Parthi

Comment: I doubt there even *is* a referrer when using the browser navigation buttons, since the *page* isn't actually referring the user anywhere.

Comment: What does this has to do with jquery ui? please read [ask]

Comment: I was using IE 11 and above versions. I can navigate the page while clicking on button one page into another page consecutively and i can create a common method in common file for to get previous Page URL. When i want to get back to the previous page i'll call the common method.

Answer (score 0):

This will go back `1` history:

```
<input action="action" type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" />
```

That will go back 1 in your history on that page.

Hope that might help you.